# no matching function for call to constructor C++ // не вызывается конструктор в C++

Tags: c++, ооп, конструктор

Помогите исправить ошибку

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;


class TEST1
{
    public: int a1;

    public: TEST1(uint8_t a)
    {
        this->a1 = a;
    };
};


class TEST2
{
    public: TEST1 a2;

    public: TEST2(uint8_t a)
    {
        this->a2 = TEST1(a);
    };
};



int main()
{
    TEST2 test = TEST2(10);
    printf("%i", test.a2.a1);
    return 0;
};
```

```
PS R:\Roma\programing\C or C++\TEST> cd "r:\Roma\programing\C or C++\TEST\" ; if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
main.cpp: In constructor 'TEST2::TEST2(uint8_t)':
main.cpp:23:5: error: no matching function for call to 'TEST1::TEST1()'
   23 |     {
      |     ^
main.cpp:11:13: note: candidate: 'TEST1::TEST1(uint8_t)'
   11 |     public: TEST1(uint8_t a)
      |             ^~~~~
main.cpp:11:13: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr TEST1::TEST1(const TEST1&)'
    7 | class TEST1
      |       ^~~~~
main.cpp:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp:7:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr TEST1::TEST1(TEST1&&)'
main.cpp:7:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
PS R:\Roma\programing\C or C++\TEST>
```

Comment: при написании собственного конструктора `TEST1(uint8_t a)`,`TEST2(uint8_t a)` другие конструкторы, на пример по-умолчанию/копирования `TEST1()`,`TEST2(TEST2 const &)` автоматически **не** будут создаваться. и вы должны их сами написать.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема  объясняет одну из причин, почему при конструировании лучше использовать список инициализации.  Плюс ко всему, много лучше избавиться от  лишных писанин и слов, если в них нет необходимости(например от слов  `public` если у класса нет закрытых членов), просто поняв, что это обычная струтура. То есть код типа:

```
struct TEST1
{
    int a1;
    TEST1(uint8_t a) : a1(a) { }
};

struct TEST2
{
    TEST1 a2;
    TEST2(uint8_t a):a2(TEST1(a)){}
};
```

будет работать в вашей программе, потому что член структур инициализируется при конструировании, а в вашем коде есть попытка создать объект `TEST1` путем вызова конструктора по умолчанию(при создании TEST2 test) и затем  его инициализировать строкой `this->a2 = TEST1(a);` Но если вы написали конструктор с аргументом, который, к тому же, не является универсальной ссылкой, то как уже сказано пользователем `AlexGlebe`, не будет автоматически генерирован конструктор по умолчанию `TEST1()`(если сам указываешь как нужно действовать, то  укажите все действия), и вам нужно будет его тоже определять, например артументу просто присвоив значение по умолчанию TEST1(uint8_t a = ...)